# How do I write from a Multi-Dimensional Array?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multi-dimensional array that is filled using a single line of Code:

> ArrayName = Worksheets("SourceDataWorkSheet).Range("A18:BM174")

The advantage of filling the array using this method, rather than a cell-by-cell loop count, is that it fills in less than a second - even for such a large data array.

**Is it possible to write the data out just as quickly?**

At the moment I am writing the data out (after finding the appropriate place to paste) cell by cell through a loop arrangement, and it's really slowing the whole process down.

What I aim to do is to be able to paste the second dimension of the array in a Column in the worksheet DestinationSheet (after there has been a loop to determine where to put it). In other words, once the destination row for Array (1, x) has been found, I want to paste the values of X into the Range(H20:AB20) (for example), but I can't work out how to paste without using the looping cell values.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it out in the same fashion - you just need to use the boundaries of the array to determine how large the target range needs to be:

```
Range("H20").Resize(ubound(ArrayName, 1), Ubound(ArrayName, 2)).Value = ArrayName
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. It's not quite returning what I'm after, though. What I would like to do it print out only the relevant row dimension at a time, e.g. when I find a match for the value in Array (1, x), print out the Values recorded in X, not the whole array. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: So you want to paste the 'column' x from the array into a row - i.e. transposed?